# Specific Order Of Execution for processes using fork and waitpid()

Tags: c, process, operating-system, synchronization, fork

I want to create 4 child processes from a parent process, using the `fork()` system call. Then I want to print some output from the processes (including their PID), in this certain order:

`P4`, `P1`, `P3`, `P2`, `P0`

`P0` is the parent process and the rest are its children. The `sleep` call shouldn't be used.

Comment: So, what is you question ?

Comment: You shouldn't depend on delays at all but simply create all of them from the parent, one at a time. Just check the result of each fork() call to see if you are the parent (create more) or not (do not create more). Yeah it's a truly awful API from the dinosaur age but that's *nix for you...

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Calling `waitpid` in the child makes no sense.

Comment: Having a process wait for itself to end makes even less sense.

Comment: No my question is can we solve the question in another manner?

Answer (score 0):

Only the parent process should call `wait` or `waitpid` on its children, to obtain their termination status. To enforce a certain order of execution between the child processes, you need some sort of an IPC mechanism. That could be an event dispatched from the parent process.

I would write something like that, using the Linux-specific `eventfd` API (file descriptors for signaling events between processes):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/eventfd.h>

int main(void) {
    pid_t child_pids[4] = { 0 };
    int events[4] = { -1 };
    int back_events[4] = { -1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        const int event_fd = eventfd(0, 0);
        const int back_event_fd = eventfd(0, 0);
        const pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
            eventfd_t value;
            eventfd_read(event_fd, &value);
            printf("Output from process %d\n", getpid());
            eventfd_write(back_event_fd, value);
            exit(0);
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            child_pids[i] = pid;
            events[i] = event_fd;
            back_events[i] = back_event_fd;
            printf("Forked process %d\n", pid);
        } else {
            perror("fork");
        }
    }

    eventfd_t value = 1;

    /* This loop signals the processes in a sequential order */
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        eventfd_write(events[i], value);
        eventfd_read(back_events[i], &value);
    }

    pid_t wpid;

    while ((wpid = wait(NULL)) > 0) {
        printf("Process %d terminated\n", wpid);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output on my system:

```
Forked process 20795
Forked process 20796
Forked process 20797
Forked process 20798
Output from process 20795
Output from process 20796
Output from process 20797
Output from process 20798
Process 20795 terminated
Process 20796 terminated
Process 20797 terminated
Process 20798 terminated
```

It wouldn't hurt to add some additional error checking around the `eventfd` calls, too.